# Is there a DRY way to patch multiple resources using kubectl v1.17?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kustomize

I'm working under some restrictions, outside of my control, namely the CI/CD pipeline and the infrastructure in general.

I've been testing my kustomizations on my local console which has v1.21, but my pipeline is running v1.17.

So `components` are out, and apparently so is patching multiple resources with the `patches` object: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/1373#issuecomment-618439078
And no, directly invoking `kustomize` (of any version) is not available either.

Not using components, I can deal with, but multi-patching support seems incredibly basic.

Here's a basic example of what I was doing:

```sh
    root
    |- kube
       |- kustomize
            |- base
            |    |- job_dir
            |    |   |- job1.yml
            |    |   |- ..
            |    |- job.patch.yml 
            |    |   # config that applies to some jobs
            |    |- kustomization.yml
            |         # resources:
            |         #   - job_dir/job1.yml
            |         #   - ..
            |         #     
            |         # patches:
            |         #   - target:
            |         #       kind: Job
            |         #     patch: |-
            |         #       - op: add
            |         #         ..
            |         #   - path: job.patch.yml
            |         #     target:
            |         #       kind: Job
            |         #       labelSelector: patchWith=job.patch
            |- overlays
                |- dev
                |   |- kustomization.yml
                |        # images: ..
                |- prod
                    |- kustomization.yml
                         # images: ..
```

executed with kubectl 1.17:

```sh
$ kubectl apply -k kube/kustomize/base
error: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field Kustomization.patchesStrategicMerge of type patch.StrategicMerge
```

executed with kubectl 1.20+:

```sh
kubectl apply -k kube/kustomize/base
job.batch/job1 created
job.batch/..
```

Without multi-patching, can I emulate the same behavior somehow?

Preferably with using some templating tool like `jinja2`.

Worth noting that the infrastructure's actual Kubernetes instance is running v1.20, so there's some restrictions there, too. (for instance, why I'm not just using indexed jobs ಠ_ಠ) So, if there's a way to

Comment: if you have `kustomize v0.3.7` or newer somewhere, you _can_ `kustomize build $dir > $filename && kubectl apply -f $filename`

Answer (score 0):

I found **a way**. This probably isn't the best way.

You can use [`kubectl patch`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#patch) to patch specific files `-f PATH`, directories `-f DIR_PATH`, kustomizations `-k DIR_PATH`, or directories recursively `-Rf DIR_PATH`.

**You should be careful, though, as this applies the patch to everything in scope.**

For instance, this is what happens when a ConfigMap is in the directory where you're applying a patch meant for jobs:

```sh
$ ls kube/kustomize/base
job.yml config.yml
$ patch='[{op: add, path: /spec/template/spec/restartPolicy, value: Never}]'
$ kubectl patch --local=true --type=json -p "$patch" -o name -R kube/kustomize/base
job.batch/job1
error: add operation does not apply: doc is missing path: "/spec/template/spec/restartPolicy": missing value
```

In this case, it's not too bad since nothing unexpected got the patch, but if you're not careful you might apply a patch to the wrong resources. Globs don't work, so you won't be able to patch based on a file pattern unless there's only one resource that matches.

So, `-f PATH` is the best, and safest.

You can compile a list of the correct files using something like this, depending on the system:

```sh
$ kust_dir="kube/kustomize/base"
$ kust_file="${kust_dir}/kustomization.yml"
$ sed -n '/^resources:\s*$/,/^[^ \t-]/p' ${kust_file} | tail -n +2 | head -n -1 | sed -i "s@\s*-\s\+@$kust_dir@" > manifest_list.tmp
```

It gets pretty complicated if you want a bulletproof way to use label selectors, but this flawed approach works for most things:

```sh
# recursive look for label anywhere in $kust_dir, output filenames, filter output by the existing list of filenames
$ grep -lre "$label:\s*$value" $kust_dir | grep -Ff manifest_list.tmp > filtered_by_label.tmp
```

As stated, it matches any label in the file. If you know the whitespace string that manifests are indented with, and they're uniform, can do this:

```sh
# indent_str="  " if it's two spaces
$ grep -lre "\($indent_str\)\{2\}$label:\s*$value" $kust_dir | grep -Ff manifest_list.tmp > filtered_by_label.tmp
```

which should only match the first label. Use `-z` and `-P` options to match multiple lines to get a better result, but it may not work on every system, and you still might need to know the number of tabs, or else use some `find -exec awk` or `find -exec sed`.

---

once you have a file list you're confident of, do something like this:

```sh
$ for file in $file_list; do
>   kubectl patch --local=true --type=json -p '$patch_str' -o yaml -f $file > $file
> done
$ kubectl apply -k kube/kustomize/base
job/job1 created
```

You can use `-R -f kube/kustomize/base/jobs` or `-k kube/kustomize/base` to apply the patch to multiple resources, but the output won't include the `---` separator, so you can't write the output to a file and then apply it without some processing. But you can tinker with that as a possible alternative.